# CLLocationManager stopUpdatingLocation when address is obtained, but address label is still empty

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, cllocationmanager

I got an app that shows current location on some labels. In `viewDidLoad` I call `[gps startUpdatingLocation];` (instance of `CLLocationManager`), so `gps` calls the relative method:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    //NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
    currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation != nil) {
        longitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.3f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
        latitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.3f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    }

    NSLog(@"Resolving the Address");
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Found placemarks: %@, error: %@", placemarks, error);
        if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0) {
            placemark = [placemarks lastObject];
            [address sizeToFit];
            address.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@\n%@ %@\n%@",
                            [self sanitizedDescription:placemark.thoroughfare],
                            [self sanitizedDescription:placemark.subThoroughfare],
                            [self sanitizedDescription:placemark.postalCode],
                            [self sanitizedDescription:placemark.locality],
                            [self sanitizedDescription:placemark.country]];

            if (address.text != NULL)
            {
                [gps stopUpdatingLocation];
            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);
        }
    } ];

}
```

So when the address is obtained, `gps` must `stopUpdatingLocation`. All works fine, but in-app `address` label **is still empty**! Why?

P.S.: `sanitizedDescription` is a simple method that returns "..." if a `placemark.value` is `nil`:

```
- (id)sanitizedDescription:(NSString *)obj
{
    if (obj == nil)
    {
        obj = @"...";
        return obj;
    }

    return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved, `address` label was too small, so I simply called `[address sizeToFit]` again in the `if` cycle:

```
        if (address.text != NULL)
        {
            [address sizeToFit];
            [gps stopUpdatingLocation];
        }
```